# C++ Read from file in nested loop and assign values to two dimensional array

Tags: c++

I have a file with zero and one. The digits represent a ASCII map I want to read from a file and place in a array. Its a lot easier create the map on a text file that manually assign them to all array places

Here is my code below. I cant understand why there is an error. I will add the error image so one can see the red line under neath the part

The result should be reading them digits from the file and inserting them into the array

Any help with this tiny error would be much appreciated

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int levelOneArray[29][29];
    ofstream levelOne;
    int digit;

    levelOne.open("levelOne.txt");
    for (int x = 0; x < 30; ++x)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < 30; ++y)
        {
            levelOne >> digit;
            int value = digit;
            levelOneArray[y][x] = digit;
        }
    }
}

//This is what is contained in the levelOne.txt file
111111111111111111111111111111
100000000000000000111000000111
101111101110001110111001110111
101111101110001110000001110001
101111101110001111111101111111
101111100000001111111100011111
101111101110001111111100011111
100000000000001111111100011111
101111110000000000111100000001
101000010111111110111100000001
101111010000000010111111111101
101111011111111010111111111101
101111000000001010111101000001
101111111111101010111101000001
100000111111101010111101011111
101110111111101010111100011111
100000111111101011111110011111
100111111111101001111110011111
100110000000000001111110000001
100000111100001000000000111001
100000100101101111111110111011
100110110101101000011000111001
100110110101101011011011111001
100000000001101011000011111001
100000000011101011111111111001
111110110011101011111111111101
100110110011101011111111111001
101100000010000000100000100001
100000000000001000000100000011
111111111111111111111111111111
```

Here are my images

Image One [Error Image One](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AxuX7.png)
Image Two [Error Image two](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vGMFm.png)

Comment: Woooh.. Ok let me try

Comment: A I see I for input and O for output right ?

Comment: Yup, also see agold's answer it is also important

Comment: Thanks very much man. Most well received !

Comment: I moved your solution to a community wiki answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your array `levelOneArray` has 29 rows and 29 columns (i.e. indices 0..28), but in your for-loop you loop until 30, which is 1 too much.

```
int levelOneArray[29][29];
//...

for (int x = 0; x < 29; ++x)
{
    for (int y = 0; y < 29; ++y)
    {
    // ..
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

*Solution by OP.*

```
int main()
{
    char levelOneArray[30][30];
    ifstream levelOne;
    char digit;

    levelOne.open("levelOne.txt");
    for (int x = 0; x < 30; ++x)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < 30; ++y)
        {
            levelOne >> digit;
            char value = digit;
            levelOneArray[y][x] = digit;
        }
    }

    for (int x = 0; x < 30; ++x)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < 30; ++y)
        {
            cout << levelOneArray[y][x];
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;

    int end;
    cin >> end;
    return 0;
}
```